# TypeError: mediasoup.Server is not a function

Tags: mediasoup

I am interested in using this example to create mediasoup based video conferencing app.
https://gitee.com/hqqshe/mediasoup-broadcast-example
but when I execute that example, shows me this error message:
TypeError: mediasoup.Server is not a function.
How can I solve this problem?!

Comment: did you run npm install first to get all the packages?